# I'm on a project trying to create a leap year generator. Every year works besides the years with the last two digits being 16 or 20

Tags: python-3.x, leap-year

Any time I type the years that end with 16 or 20, example: 2016 or 3020, it just ends. The code I am using is below, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
year = int(input("Year??? ")

if year % 4 == 0:
    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year % 400 == 0:
            print("Leap year.")
        elif year != 0:
            print("Not leap year.")
else:
    print("Not leap year.")
```

Comment: A lot more than that doesn't work. You have no case for `year % 4 == 0` but `year % 100 != 0`

Comment: Thank you @hobbs , i was able to figure it out due to your comment. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
year = int(input("Year???"))
if (year%400 == 0):
          print("Not a leap year")
elif (year%100 == 0): # elif is preferable to nested if in most cases
          print("Not a leap year")
elif (year%4 == 0):
          print("This is a leap year!")
else:
          print("This is not a leap year")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
year = int(input("Year???"))

if not year % 4 and (year % 100 or not year % 400):
    print("This is a leap year!")
else:
    print("Not a leap year")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
year = int(input())
if (year % 4)==0 and (year % 100)>0:
    print('it is a leapyear')
elif (year % 400) ==0:
    print('it is a leapyear')
else:
    print('it is not a leapyear')
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?